# Vue3: redundant route.push, unexpected route redirect after some navigation

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

Good day all !

I have an unwanted redirect  occurring from a manual route.push, after some navigation steps, as if it had been cached in history stack.

Edit: the only alternative i have found, is to no longer need home dependency and copying it to [A], then, no need to pushing the route causing the issue (but i dont like this code duplication).

Said more exactly, [A] has two uses, first is a data listing, second one is to fetch and print data from elements of this list (home has already the code for fetching and printing), then i call [home] from [A] with suitable parameters to avoid code duplication.
The parameters are provided by a custom store (not pinia store)

Any clue ?

Note: i'm using vue3/router4 and only composition features are used

Code overview:

```
component Home
    // do something...
    // click methods to go to [B]

component A
    setup()
    {
    // called by @click
    search = (id)
    {
        store.query.value = id
        route.push({name:'home'})
    }
    ...

component B
    // do something
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
    - opening app with [home] comp
    - go to [A], 
    - then search click (to prepare query for home api call)
    - comming from [A] to home (by route.push...)
    - button click to go to [B] from home
    - [B] loads but the route change unexpectedly to home before [B] route end 
     my logs say the route is already redirected when we arrive in the route guard beforeEach()
```

here is a summary of the router code

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/', // is [home]
    name: 'root',
    component: Home,
    meta: { title: false }
  },
  {
    path: '/categories', // is [A]
    name: 'categories',
    component: () => import('./views/Categories.vue'),
    meta: { title: 'route.categories' }
  },
  {
    path: '/tool/:id', // is [B]
    name: 'tool',
    component: () => import('./views/Tool.vue'),
    meta: { title: false }
  },
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    name: '404',
    component: () => import('./components/404.vue'),
    meta: { title: 'route.404' }
  }
]

export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  navigationFallback:
  {
    rewrite: '/',
    exclude: ['/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}', '/css/*']
  }
})
```

Expected behavior :

- I would like to void this not wished redirect

I tried to use route.replace instead of push, nothing changed,
commented many piece of code, and this is only when i comment the route.push from [A], that the redirect no longer occurs.
I suspect the route.push in [A] to be cached somewhere. I can't understand why it runs twice (at call, and after two route navigation steps...)

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. Please clean it by: (1) Describe your raw problem, expected, and actual behavior. Don't add any assumptions to it to reduce confusion for the reader. (2) Describe your code flow clearly. Show your code. (3) Create a minimal reproduction of your problem on an online tool like stackblitz.com

Comment: You're right, i go to isolate the issue on stackblitz !